# Understanding Argument Type

Tags: idris

What's the meaning of this `(a, b, c: Nat)` argument in:

```
g : (a, b, c: Nat) -> Int
g (a,b,c) = 42
```

?

Evidently the first argument is a triple, i.e. 3-tuple.

Answer (score 3):

```
g: (a,b,c: Nat) -> Int
```

is just a short cut for

```
g: (a: Nat) -> (b: Nat) -> (c: Nat) -> Int
```

If you expand on `g: (a,b,c: Nat) -> Int` you will get

```
g: (a, b, c: Nat) -> Int
g a b c = ?g_rhs
```

A named tuple parameter (AFAIK idris does not have built-in triples) would be specified as

```
g: (a: (Nat, Nat)) -> Int
g a = ?g_rhs
```